# Socket.io configuration resulting in error 404

Tags: node.js, http, https, socket.io

I tried to setup `socket.io` into my node server in order to make a messaging function for my app but having problem getting to function despite doing test app correct.

### server.js:

```
/* long list of requires */
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var config = require('./config');

var app = express();


var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

/* ssl setup */

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(8000); // opens the port
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(4433); // for the ssl
```

index.html

```
..bunch of code like bootstrap and angular.js

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
    });
</script>
```

I tried to run the site on localhost:8000.

Despite all that, I'm getting error 404 in the console:

> GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LnM0Fd3 404

I'm not sure what went wrong with the set up process of socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating three servers, only one of which gets the Socket.io

```
// createServer No 1
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


// ...

// createServer No 2
http.createServer(app).listen(8000); // opens the port
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.

// createServer No 3
https.createServer(options, app).listen(4433); // for the ssl
```

You should probably only create one server and add the socket.io call to *that* one.

If you create only the Port `8000` server, you could add it like this:

```
// (exactly your code, except for the "var server = " in front.
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8000); // opens the port
// the next line is new:
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

notice that you'll also have to move the `io.on......` part below that line.

Comment: so how would I add the socket.io to the 8000 server? like what would that look like? I need the third server for ssl as it running the port 443 when I put it on aws.

Comment: Also his client connects to http (`io.connect('http://localhost:8000')`)